# Creating a delay in for-loop iterations

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, settimeout

I've written the following function with hopes to add 1px onto the top margin to animate a window sliding out of the page.

Currently it works fine and removes the window from the page, However I'm having problems creating the delay interval in each iteration of the for loop. I've thought about using `setTimeout()`, but with this I cant just break; the for loop I have to call a function,

Any ideas?

```
function slideOut() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("cInstructs");
    var orig = 66;
    for(i=0; i<2000; i++) {
        orig++;
        obj.style.marginTop = orig+"px";
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Timers loops will vary widely in different machines and browsers. You need to use setTimeout()

Comment: jQuery and other frameworks handle animation internally, so you don't have to worry about it. Worth considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion would be to check the jQuery .slideDown() function- http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: Whilst not the easiest answer, this seems to be the proper way to do things so is worth the extra effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;

function incrAndDelay(i) {
setTimeout(...);
i+=1;
return i;
}


function slideOut() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("cInstructs");
    var orig = 66;
    for(i=0; i<2000; incrAndDelay(i)) {
        orig++;
        obj.style.marginTop = orig+"px";
        }
    };
```

Still have to call a function but not in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

```
var intId;
function slideOut() {
    clearInterval(intId);
    var count = 0;
    var obj = document.getElementById("cInstructs");
    var orig = 66;
    intId = setInterval(function(){
        orig++;
        obj.style.marginTop = orig+"px";
        if((++count == 2000)){
            clearInterval(intId);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```